# Why Isn't the jQuery .index() function behaving like I expect here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues understanding why my jQuery index() function is not performing the way I expect it to. Perhaps I'm not understanding this. Let me show you.

I set up a new array. We'll use this later:

```
var mySources = new Array();
```

I have 5 images on my page:

```
<div id="homeSlides">
       <img src="../images/homeImages/00.jpg" width="749" height="240" alt="myAltTag" />
       <img src="../images/homeImages/01.jpg" width="749" height="240" alt="myAltTag"  />
       <img src="../images/homeImages/02.jpg" width="749" height="240" alt="myAltTag" />
       <img src="../images/homeImages/03.jpg" width="749" height="240" alt="myAltTag" />
       <img src="../images/homeImages/04.jpg" width="749" height="240" alt="myAltTag" />
```

I put them all in an jQuery object, like this:

```
var myImages = $("#homeSlides img");
```

Now, for each one, I extract the src attribute and push  it into the mySources array like this:

```
 $(myImages).each( function(index) {
        mySources[index] = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Now, I will run the array to the FireBug console to make sure it worked.

This...

```
console.log(mySources);
```

...returns this...

```
["../images/homeImages/00.jpg", "../images/homeImages/01.jpg", "../images/homeImages/02.jpg", "../images/homeImages/03.jpg", "../images/homeImages/04.jpg"]
```

...which is what I expect.

Now I do this:

```
var myVar = $(myImages).eq(2).attr('src');
```

Tracing that variable now...

```
console.log(myVar);
```

...returns this...

```
../images/homeImages/02.jpg
```

But then when I do this...

```
console.log('Index of ' + myVar + " is: " + ($(myVar).index( mySources )) );
```

...it returns this:

```
 Index of ../images/homeImages/02.jpg is: -1
```

This is throwing me. Why would it return -1 for "not found" when it should be retunring 2. It does mat the second slot in the mySources array, no?

Comment: `myImages` is already a jQuery object. You don't need to do `$(myImages)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use index() on an array. It is not intended to be used for anything other than jQuery  element objects.

Using $.inArray() would be the better method

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thank you, and thanks to the others who responded as well. Always appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You may have the function backwards. Can you try:

```
$(mySources).index( myVar )
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actually `$.inArray(myVar, mySources)` is the correct way

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos: Quite so. jQuery's argument order is a source of ongoing frustration to me. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Same happens to me sometimes :)